# Is this the best way to code this small calculator in Javascript using Object Oriented approach?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to OOJS. I have made a simple calculator. After form submission, it creates an object and simply displays the result. I'm wondering if this is the best possible way to code this in OOJS ?

```
let form = document.forms['cal-form'];
form.addEventListener('submit', calculate);

  function calculate(e) {
    //prevent default form submission
    e.preventDefault();
    //get form values
    let num1 = parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value);
    let num2 = parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value);
    let op = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value;

    //create object constructor function
    function Calculate(num1, num2, op){
      this.num1 = num1;
      this.num2 = num2;
      this.op = op;
    }

    Calculate.prototype.result = function() {
      let res;
      switch (op) {
        case 'add':
          res = this.num1 + this.num2;
          break;
        case 'sub':
          res = this.num1 - this.num2;
          break;
        case 'mul':
          res = this.num1 * this.num2;
          break;
        case 'div':
          res = this.num1 / this.num2;
          break;
        default:
          res= 'Error! No operation selected.';
      }
      return res;
    };

    //create an object
    let cal = new Calculate(num1, num2, op);
    //display result
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = cal.result();

  }
};
```

Comment: Impossible to say without the code, but even with the code, this sounds overly broad  and opinion-based for SO

Comment: edit: I have posted the code

Comment: Take this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: There’s nothing object-oriented about this, it’s just making a function call more complicated.

Comment: @Ry- I'm new to OOJS. It would be helpful if you can share how this code could be improved.

Comment: I advise you to use `classes`, they offer everything you need to code OO. Check this link : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-classes-in-javascript

Comment: @DavidAlvarez: It can be improved by just making it a function. Which isn’t OO either, but it doesn’t need to be. Eventually you’ll come across a task that’s well-suited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here could be one answer using class :

```js
class Calculator {
  add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }
  
  sub(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  }
  
  mul(a, b) {
    return a * b;
  }
  
  div(a, b) {
    if (b == 0) throw new Error('div by 0 not allowed');
    return a / b;
  }
}

const a = 12;
const b = 6;

const cal = new Calculator();

const AplusB = cal.add(a,b);
const AminusB = cal.sub(a, b);
const AtimesB = cal.mul(a, b);
const AdivB = cal.div(a, b);

const results = [AplusB, AminusB, AtimesB, AdivB];

console.log(results);
```

I think this approach is more OO than yours because we can say the object is the calculator. For me it's weird to have a `Calculate` object as you have